# Python: Sorting circles returned from cv2 HoughCircles by radius

Tags: python, sorting, opencv, numpy

I'm trying to optimize my circles recognizing script.
The idea is to sort the circles returned by HoughCircle function (cv2) by radius (from greatest to smallest).
for example:

```
circles=cv2.HoughCircles(image,bla....bla)
circles2=sorting_by_radius(circles)           #your help is needed to do this
for c in circles2                             
    do_my_istructions
```

I've tried `.sort` method and `np.argsort` but something goes wrong.

Comment: Can you provide a fuller example and describe what exactly goes wrong in the options you've tried?

Comment: Solved:
the error I did:
  circles=cv2.HoughCircles(image,bla....bla)
  circles2=sorted(circles,key=lambda x:x[2],reverse=true)
the problem is that the info of position and radius of each circle are stored in circles[0]

so the the right way is:
  circles=cv2.HoughCircles(image,bla....bla)
  circles2=sorted(circles[0],key=lambda x:x[2],reverse=true)

thank you

Comment: I have not the right reputation to answer by myself now.

Answer (score 2):

On behalf of user3157906 (in order for code formatting to be applied)

Solved!

The error I did:

```
circles=cv2.HoughCircles(image,bla....bla)
circles2=sorted(circles,key=lambda x:x[2],reverse=true)
```

The problem is that the info of position and radius of each circle is stored in `circles[0]`

So the right way is:

```
circles=cv2.HoughCircles(image,bla....bla)
circles2=sorted(circles[0],key=lambda x:x[2],reverse=true)
```